# Is it OK to compare an int and a long in Java

Tags: java, long-integer

Is it OK to compare an int and a long in Java...

```
long l = 800L
int i = 4

if (i < l) {
 // i is less than l
}
```

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 120):

Yes, that's fine. The `int` will be implicitly converted to a `long`, which can always be done without any loss of information.

Comment: Just to add a scenario that came across. `int a = Integer.MAX_VALUE; long b = a;` the following gives false. `print(a + 1 > b)` Seems the implicit conversion happens after `a+1` is stored as an `int`

Comment: @WeishiZeng: Yes, absolutely. Both operands in `a + 1` are `int` - so that addition happens in `int` arithmetic, then the conversion to `long`, then the comparison.

Comment: I don't think this is a true assessment. Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1 , caused an Integer overflow which in case of java causes the new variable to be to Integer.MIN_VALUE. So you seeing false on this (a + 1 > b) is an expected behaviour.

Answer (score -5):

You can compare long and int directly however this is **not recommended.**

It is always better to cast long to integer before comparing as long value can be above int limit

```
long l = Integer.MAX_VALUE;       //2147483647
int i = Integer.MAX_VALUE;        //2147483647
System.out.println(i == l);       // true
 l++;                             //2147483648
 i++;                             //-2147483648
System.out.println(i == l);       // false
System.out.println(i == (int)l);  // true
```

Comment: Why is it not recommended?

Comment: It is not better to cast long to integer before comparing, on the contrary, that can lead to overflow and thus to wrong results.

Comment: @intentionallyleftblank : it is not recommended because both have different range and even if we store same value in both variables output will be different.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : i completely agree casting long to int is not better however this scenario it is required, for overflow cases comparison only

Comment: No it is not required in this scenario, it is even incorrect in this scenario. When comparing int and long, the int is automatically cast to long and that works correctly. Casting the long to int can lead to incorrect results, and is thus the wrong thing to do. Your example even points that out, because of course -2147483648 is not equal to 2147483648

Comment: @MarkRotteveel : can you please explain me how can we compare int and long if we have case explained in my answer after l++ and i++ ?, logically they have same value

Comment: The only thing your example points out is that the choice of `int` for `i` is the wrong choice, because the overflow shouldn't have happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177625/discussion-between-manasi-and-mark-rotteveel).